# Pause game on go to main menu in symbian^3 through QML

Tags: qt, symbian, qml, symbian3

I made a game for symbian^3 with QML .
and I stumbled upon one problem.
I don't know how to pause my game when the game is go to background (e.g : home button pressed) . especially the music. it cannot stop playing at all. 
I tried to use (status == PageStatus.Inactive) but it have no use.
is there any workaround to do this through QML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Qt.application.active` to check whether your application is in the foreground or not.

More information can be found [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qml-qt.html#application-prop).